# Sonarqube and System.out or System.err during Logger initialization?

Tags: java, logging, sonarqube

I began use sonarqube today, launched on a pair of project.

Both have a logger library, even if different, anyway both during configuration or initialization there is some sysout/syserr if something goes wrong, for example:

```
public class LogManager {
  ...
  public void log(Level level, Category category, String message, Throwable exception) {
        LoggersManagerFactory loggersManagerFactory = LoggersManager.getLoggersManagerFactory();
        if(loggersManagerFactory == null) {
          System.err.println("...");
          ...
}
```

Sonarqube alerts to remove System.err and System.out with a Logger.

But in those points Logger is not yet configured or initialized.

What's right way to manage Logger or Sonarqube in these cases?

Comment: Simply ignore the warning at this point? Sonar's rule are a  guideline, not a requirement. If one rule doesn't make sense at a specific point, you don't have to adhere to it.

Comment: Thank for reply @maio290. Sonarqube rules are managed by a centralized team and analysis is mandatory in my actual organization, before contact internal sonarqube managment team, or other internal teams which could answer, I was wondering if this is a general issue with a best practice approach...

Comment: I have done exactly the same thing.  When initializing the logging, it’s a reasonable action, and I’m not sure I can think of a better choice.  And as maio290 pointed out, Sonar is not an authority on good coding, it’s just some collected observations on potential errors and potential antipatterns.